# How to do subdomain transfer to other subdomain via WHM

Tags: server, subdomain, config, transfer, whm

I want to refer one subdomain from another server to another subdomain on other server.

For example.

new.example.com is on SERVER1

dev.mydomain.com is on SERVER2

I need that when customer enter to new.example.com he see the website of dev.mydomain.com

I changed the DNS A records of new.example.com to the IP of dev.mydomain.com, but I need to do something on dev.mydomain.com

What configurations can I do on dev.mydomain via WHM .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead working with DNS & IP the smart thing you could do is redirect new.example.com to dev.mydomain.com. You can do this by accessing Redirection option under example.com Cpanel account.

Comment: But if I do redirection the customers will see dev.mydomain.com domain instead of example.com. How can we do that the customers don't see mydomain.com?